# Como usar resources de diferentes línguas no C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows

É o seguinte, entrando em alguns tutoriais consegui criar dois resources para minha aplicação, e ambos estão funcionando, pois quando altera a linguagem no campo de linguagem das propriedades do Form, os textos são atualizados para a língua escolhida. Porém eu não sei como alterar o idioma dentro da aplicação, pois eu criei um form de opções que serve para o usuário mudar o idioma da aplicação e eu não sei como fazer ele mudar o idioma do form.
Por favor me ajudem.[image: Os dois resources]